# How do I get Tkinter.Entry to stop processing input while the function bound to it is running?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a Tkinter.Entry box that I have bound to the  event. The function that triggers adds a new Entry and moves the focus to it.  With regular keyboard input, it works fine.

I'm using a scanner gun [similar to this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078SQ91FB) that stores the codes it scans.  When done, you scan a control code that exports all of the scans at once.  When exporting, it acts like it types in a code, presses Return/Enter, types the next one, presses enter, etc.

Instead of printing each code in its own entry, it's printing the first code and part of the second, adding an entry, printing the rest of the second code and part of the third, adding an entry, etc.

My understanding is that user input should queue until the function bound to the event is finished.  Why is it continuing to print during the function?  I know it's printing **during** the function because when I add more operations to the function (slowing down its execution), the problem is worse.  More of the input is printed in the same entry **after** it's supposed to have moved on to the next one.

When I export from the gun to Excel or Google sheets, it correctly gives each line its own new cell and you can see the program slowing as it works through the input queue.  Why is Tkinter working differently?  Is this something I can fix?

The function:

```py
    def add_entry(self, event: tk.Event | None = None, value: str = "") -> None:

        ent_ifn: ctk.Entry = ctk.Entry(self.frm_items)
        ent_ifn.insert(0, value)

        ent_ifn.bind("<Return>", self.add_entry)

        ent_ifn.grid(row=self.frm_items.grid_size()[1], column=0, sticky="ew")
        ent_ifn.focus_set()
```

P.S. I'm actually using CustomTkinter, but when I switch the Entry to normal Tkinter the problem is the same.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the purpose of your program here is? It seems that your function is recursive (since you're binding the function to an entry inside itself). How exactly does the scanner export its data and why do you need to use tkinter to capture that?

Comment: @CmdCoder858 That's a good point about the recursion! I should have caught that. And if this scanner operates anything like similar ones I've used, it instantiates itself as a Human Interface Device and essentially "types" in the data it scans as if it were a keyboard.

Comment: if it uses input similar to a keyboard it feels to me like tkinter is unnecessary. If its ok for the device to have focus of a window, then I would just create a program that runs in the command prompt, along the lines of `while 1: codes.append(input())` to add to a list every time enter is pressed. If you do want to stick with tkinter, I would recommend having the callback record and then erase the text in the Entry widget, since this would likely have a much lower overhead than spawning and refocusing a new widget.

Comment: @CmdCoder858 I'm using Tkinter because Python is what I know and sticking these users in front of a command line will end very poorly.  This is only one portion of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible (read: likely) that the scanner is instantiating itself as a HID, like a keyboard. It may be that the scanner is 'typing' in the codes faster than the tkinter event loop can consume them. You could try using `sleep()` to effectively slow down the scanner's typing:

```
from time import sleep
```

```
    ...  # code omitted for brevity
    # bind to the key press event
    ent_ifn.bind("<Key>", self.on_key)

def on_key(self, event):
    if event.keysym != 'Return':
        sleep(0.05)  # sleep for ~50mS
```

Normally I wouldn't recommend using `sleep()` within a tkinter application, as the GUI will hang during the sleep, but since the user isn't typing these codes in manually it might be worth a shot.

Another thought I had is that you might try calling `update()` on your root `Tk` window instead of using `sleep()`, i.e.:

```
def on_key(self, event):
    if event.keysym != 'Return':
        self.update() 
        # 'self' is assuming this function exists in your root class that
        # inherits from 'tk.Tk'...you get the idea
```

Again, normally you wouldn't want to slam the event loop with calls to `update()`, but it might help in this case. Barring that, you could try `update_idletasks()` instead!

---

***EDIT:***
The more I think about this, the less convinced I am that `sleep()` will work...because that will also block the tkinter event loop.

Comment: I replaced the Entry with a Textbox and am splitting the data on newlines when the user clicks submit.  I'll try the update thing when I get back from vacation in two weeks.  Even if it doesn't work, it'll be a good experiment.

Comment: @Brandon that’s not a bad idea! And I’m curious to see if this works out for you - it’s certainly an interesting problem. I’m sorry I don’t have similar equipment to test this out on my end. Enjoy your vacation!